# swipe from left to right and right to left in android

Tags: android

I have SwipeActivity. when I swipe from right to left, I want to go activity B and when swipe left to right  go to activity C. but my code didn't work. please help me.

my SwipeActivity is:

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
    mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

 private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {

                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {

                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } 

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Intent in = new Intent(SwipeActivity.this,page1Activity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Intent in = new Intent(SwipeActivity.this,page2Activity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

}

Comment: What behavior do you observe? If your application is crashing or you get an Exception, what does your logcat say?

Comment: Did you try stepping through with the debugger?  I'd verify that the view you are setting the on touch listener to is actually firing on touch.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use fragments, and a ViewPager that contains the fragment inside the activity.

Check this is example: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

I hope that it ll be usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Android ViewPager for better UI experience and use Fragment instead of activity. you
can save the more time using ViewPager instead of developing custom swipe. have a look on to following examples.

[1. ViewPager  Tab Indicator](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

[2. ViewPager Circle Style](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-circle-style-example/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using onTouch listener.  use its onDown and on up events.   take the coordinate in onDown
and onUp then compare them. if xUp< xDown = leftswipe and the opposite  for left swipe.(do not forget to adjust sensivity by adding a margin like : (if distance (upX,downX)>50))

here is a sample code :

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


                int xDown=0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                xDown= event.getRawX();

            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){


            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                                 if(Math.abs(xDown-evet.getRawX())>50)

                                      if(xDown-evet.getRawX()>0){
                                         //left
                                     }
                                     else{
                                         //right
                                     }


                                 }


                            }
```